# How to display sharp icons in wxWIdgets

Tags: c++, icons, wxwidgets, ico

I am displaying `icon` for my app using `wxWidgets`. I am using following code and using a `.ico file` with `128*128` dimensions. but the icon displayed is not sharp. How should I make it sharp? 
I am using following code:

```
bool ImageFileToIcon(wxString &path, wxIcon &icon)
{
  wxImage image;
  if (!image.LoadFile(path))
  {
     wxLogError(wxT("Couldn't load image from '%s'."), path.c_str());
     return false;
  }
  icon.CopyFromBitmap(image);
  return true;
}

someFunction()
{
  wxIcon tempIcon;
  ImageFileToIcon(IconImagePath, tempIcon);
  SetIcon(tempIcon);
}
```

what should I do, should I use .ico file with less dimension or do I need to change code? Is there anything like .ico files contain all dimensions and we have to adjust it according to screen resolution. How to do that in wxWidgets?

Comment: I am loading icon runtime.

Answer (score 2):

`wxIcon` under Windows is special as it can contain several representations of the same picture at different resolutions, while `wxImage` only contains a single image. So when you load an `.ico` file into `wxImage` you lose all but one of the icons.

Instead, you should use the specialized [wxIconBundle](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.3/classwx_icon_bundle.html) class instead. It will also make your code much simpler, basically you just can

```
SetIcons(wxIconBundle(IconImagePath));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer from VZ. is outdated because the API changed in the version 3.1.3.
Now you would do an image icon like this:

```
wxInitAllImageHandlers(); // Init Image Handlers first
SetIcons(wxIconBundle("your/path/to/your/logo/or/image")); // watch out for the s in the function call SetIcons(), not SetIcon() anymore
```

Comment: You're right, thanks, I'll update my answer accordingly.